# "Unable to load dynamic library" on WordPress blogs error log?

Tags: wordpress, error-log

I am getting the following massage in the error log files of my WordPress blogs:

```
[10-Oct-2010 04:37:43] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20060613/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20060613/pdo.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
[10-Oct-2010 04:37:43] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20060613/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20060613/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php configuration is broken or you deleted the php.ini file. Check your php install, check php.ini, or ask your webhost.